# API PHP no recibe valores desde axios

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

Espero se encuentren bien.

Tengo una duda, estoy haciendo una petición post con axions a una api que hice en php,
le envío desde axios un json con las credenciales de inicio de sesion, pero al momento
de imprimirlo con echo desde php solamente me tira campos vacios.

les muestro mi peticion axios y donde imprimo en php

De antemano les agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Axios 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PHP 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Al mandarlos con el formato JSON no los va a tomar como `$_POST`, debes usar `php://input` y convertirlo a objeto o en su defecto cambiar el header de Axios para que los mande como application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

```
$credentials = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) );

$username = $credentials->username;
```

O en Axios.

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
};

const url = `${ENDPOINT_PATH}/user/login`;

axios.post(url, credentials, config).then().catch();
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Luis!, de hecho encontré la manera de mandarlo como si hubiera sido desde un formulario para atraparlo con $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

Esto fue lo que hice para mandarlo como si hubiera sido de un formulario.

```
   import axios from "axios";
    
    const ENDPOINT_PATH = "http://localhost:8080/reporteador/";
    const config = {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"}
    export default {
    
      signIn(user, password) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        const credentials = {
          "username":user,
          "password":password
        }
          formData.set('credentials',JSON.stringify(credentials));
          return axios.post(ENDPOINT_PATH + "user/signIn",formData,config)
        }
    };
```